# Rspec controller test - how to stub and/or test custom objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, controller, rspec-rails

Below is passing!

**Controller code:**

```
class OrdersController
  def create
    ...
    @order.save
  end
end
```

**Spec code:**

```
describe OrdersController do
  it "should call save method" do
    Order.any_instance.should_receive(:save)
    post :create
  end
end
```

But if only it were that easy... I have some custom job objects that are executed after the save, so the code actually looks like this:

Controller code:

```
class OrdersController
  def create
    ...
    @order.save
    RoadrunnerEmailAlert.new.async.perform(@order.id, true)
    CalendarInvite.new.async.perform(@order.id)
    RoadrunnerTwilioAlert.new.async.perform(@order.id)
  end
end
```

I would love to test that the custom objects are receiving the chain of methods with the right parameters, but not sure how, short of creating something in the spec code like this:

```
before do
  class RoadrunnerEmailAlert
    def async
    end
  end
end
```

But that's so contrived, it certainly isn't right... advice appreciated!

Comment: Can you try something like this ? This will help for others too.
`RoadrunnerEmailAlert.new.async.stubs(:perform).with('some_id', true).returns('your_expected_result')`

Comment: That doesnt' work, but may because the nature of this job, I get `undefined method `stubs' for #<Celluloid::CellProxy(CalendarInvite:0x3ff5ce0efa5c)>` But even if I were to call the objet inside the job, `OrderMailer.new(id, true).deliver` I'll get something like `wrong number of arguments` which implying that it's not stubbing

Comment: what you should be concerned with in this controller test is A) that the Order object is saved and B) that each of the async jobs are fired off. I strongly recommend not testing which methods are called in the action, but what the outcome of the action is. That said, your test should assert that the Order record is in the DB and that the result of each async job is correct. Many async job frameworks have test setups for this purpose. What async job framework are you using? Sidekiq?

Comment: @Chris I agree, I'm trying to check that the async is fired off, but NOT based on outcome, because the framework I'm using is somewhat... screwy in that regard (not a popular framework, not really maintained, legacy code, but still it's there). I'm just not sure the best way to check that the async is fired

Comment: gotcha. `expect_any_instance_of(RoadrunnerEmailAlert).to receive(:async)` should help you test that `#async` gets called. In your framework what type of object is returned by `#async`?

Comment: That worked... in testing, I keep forgetting the difference between a method on a class vs an instance of that class ugh....

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps other people... this is a very comprehensive answer.

**Context & design notes**

1. The async framework is Sucker Punch gem
   (http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/why-i-wrote-the-sucker-punch-gem/).
   Back then, this was the easiest thing for me to use after looking at
   Delayed Job, Sidekick, etc
2. Basically it works like this: in Controller reference a Job that then references anything else (in my case, some POROs)
3. If I were really rigidly testing, I'd want to test that A) the Controller calls the Job appropriately and passes the right parameters, and B) the Job calls the appropriate POROs and passes the right parameters. But instead, I just tested that the Controller calls the appropriate POROs and passes the right parameters, i.e., the Jobs are already working.

**Controller code**

```
@order.save
RoadrunnerEmailAlert.new.async.perform(@order.id, true)
CalendarInvite.new.async.perform(@order.id)
RoadrunnerTwilioAlert.new.async.perform(@order.id)
```

**Job code**

```
# app/jobs/roadrunner_email_alert.rb
class RoadrunnerEmailAlert
  include SuckerPunch::Job
  def perform(order_id, require_tos)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
        OrderMailer.success_email(order_id, require_tos).deliver
    end
  end
end

# app/jobs/calendar_invite.rb
class CalendarInvite
  include SuckerPunch::Job
  def perform(order_id)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
      CreateCalendar.new(order_id).perform
    end
  end
end

# app/jobs/roadrunner_twilio_alert.rb
class RoadrunnerTwilioAlert
  include SuckerPunch::Job
  def perform(order_id)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
        CreateAlert.new(order_id).perform
    end
  end
end
```

**Test code**

The really big thing here that I don't know why I keep forgetting (but only in testing) is class vs. instance of class. For the POROs, since I'm instantiating the object, I needed to test 2 different "layers" (first that the object is instantiated appropriately, second that the instantiated object is acted upon appropriately).

```
require 'sucker_punch/testing/inline'

describe "Controller code" do
  before do
    OrderMailer.any_instance.stub(:success_email)

    mock_calendar = CreateCalendar.new(1)
    CreateCalendar.stub(:new).and_return(mock_calendar)
    CreateCalendar.any_instance.stub(:perform)

    mock_alert = CreateAlert.new(1)
    CreateAlert.stub(:new).and_return(mock_alert)
    CreateAlert.any_instance.stub(:perform)
  end

  it "should call appropriate async jobs" do
    expect_any_instance_of(OrderMailer).to receive(:success_email).with(1, true)

    expect(CreateCalendar).to receive(:new).with(1)
    expect_any_instance_of(CreateCalendar).to receive(:perform)

    expect(CreateAlert).to receive(:new).with(1)
    expect_any_instance_of(CreateAlert).to receive(:perform)

    post :create
  end
end
```